# "The control has not been licensed for this machine" error while using True DB grid control pro 6.0 in vb6 project

Tags: vb6

I am using True DB grid control pro 6.0 in vb6 project on xp machine and facing no issues.
 I am trying to use the same control in vb6 project on windows 7 while acccessing the tool i am getting the  error control has not been lecensed for this machine.
Please help in this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Did you run the install for the TrueGrid package?

Look in Control Panel, Add/Remove Programs, you should see "APEX True DBGrid Pro 6.0" listed.

Comment: It is not listed in both xp and windows7 machines. but i am not facing any problems while using the control in xp machine.

Comment: Just run the install package for the TrueGrid. When you bought it you should have got a disk or a download.